# MacBook Air (2012) Toshiba SSD enclosure / connector

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, enclosures

Recently, my A1466 MacBook Air (2012) suffered some water damage. Since then, it can’t boot up anymore. I pulled the hard drive with the hope of transferring the files to either an external hard drive or a completely new MacBook.

To get to the point, I’m looking for some enclosure adapter to fit my Toshiba SSD drive (see images below). However, most of the ones I’ve found online indicate mine is *not compatible with Toshiba or third-party SSDs*. Does anyone have some insight into what enclosure may work in my case?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably a PCIe or mSATA SSD, though with the front having no pins, mSATA is more likely. It is _very unlikely_ to be M.2, because that standard did not exist back then. // For easier copy and paste: The model number is THNSNS128GMFP.

Comment: Thank you for this. Just curious: why would the front have no pins?

Comment: Check out this one from Other World Computing: [OWC Envoy (OWCMAU3ENVOY12)](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENVOY12/). As the fine print states it is made for this drive: “The OWC Envoy enclosure has been specifically designed for use ONLY with the factory SSD found installed in Apple MacBook Air 2012 models.”

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited for the [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.